# Cannot fix "Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am creating a sns-like web application. As one of the functions, I am trying to display all posts users made. However, my code shows nothing and get an error on console saying "Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function". I am totally a beginner in Javascript, react and firebase. Could anyone look into my code? Thank you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./Post.css";
import Posts from "./Posts.js";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { collection, doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ImageUpload from "./ImageUpload.js";

function Post( {user} ) {
    const db = getFirestore();
    const navigate = useNavigate("");
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState('');
    const colRef = collection(db, 'posts');

  useEffect(()=>
    onSnapshot(colRef,(snapshot) => {
        setPosts(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                return{
                    post: doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id
                };
            })
        );
    }),
  []);

    return (
        <div className = "post">
            <ImageUpload username = {user?.displayName} />

            {
                posts.map(({id, post}) => (
                    <Posts key = {id} 
                    postId = {id} 
                    origuser = {user?.displayName}
                    username = {post.username}
                    userId = {user.uid}
                    caption =  {post.caption}
                    imageUrl = {post.imageUrl}
                    noLikes = {post.noLikes}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to initialise `posts` as an array, currently you have it as a `string` and in the string prototype there is no `.map` function.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

After that you need to make sure that in the `setPosts` call you also pass an array. By looking at the example it seems like already it is `snapshot.docs.map`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 {
             posts && posts.map(({id, post}) => (
                    <Posts key = {id} 
                    postId = {id} 
                    origuser = {user?.displayName}
                    username = {post.username}
                    userId = {user.uid}
                    caption =  {post.caption}
                    imageUrl = {post.imageUrl}
                    noLikes = {post.noLikes}
                    />
                ))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

define your state as a array

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

then add extra validation layer on the map method

{

```
posts && posts.length > 0 && posts.map(({id, post}) => (
    <Posts key = {id} 
    postId = {id} 
    origuser = {user?.displayName}
    username = {post.username}
    userId = {user.uid}
    caption =  {post.caption}
    imageUrl = {post.imageUrl}
    noLikes = {post.noLikes}
    />
))
```

}